# Adding a button on a specific page with backlinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First post, so i'm a newbie in StackOverflow.  I'm trying for several days to make appear a Return button on a page form but only on a specific one. 
So, I was advised to use backlink to make it appears.

Here's my code from the form where I want the return button

```
<% if @backlink.present? %>
  <div class="spacer30"></div>
    <% if @backlink == 'infos' %>
        path = membre_path(menu: 'infos')
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<%= link_to "Retour",  path, class: "btn-rounded btn-turquoise btn-small"  %>
```

Here's my code controller

```
 def edit
  super do |user|
    puts "TEST PARAMS BACKLINK #{params[:backlink]}"
    @backlink = params[:backlink]
  end
end
```

and my route's :

```
get 'change_password', to: 'users/registrations#edit'
put 'update' => 'users/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
get 'edit_password', to: 'users/registrations#edit', :as => 'user_edit'
```

So i should have in my log my PUTS 'TEST PARAMS BACKLINK' but nothing appear, only :

```
Started GET "/change_password.1?backlink=infos" for ::1 at 2017-10-04 10:07:41 +0200
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#edit as 
Parameters: {"backlink"=>"infos"}
User Load (9.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1       ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Rendering users/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered users/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (14.4ms)
Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (4.0ms)
Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 231ms (Views: 217.0ms | ActiveRecord: 9.1ms)
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Many thanks.

Comment: I dont understand what you're trying to do with `super do |user|`. Also, are you using devise?

Comment: Indeed, that was a mistake from me. 
I just deleted some stuff in my edit function, like this : 
      def edit
        @backlink = params[:backlink]
        super
      end

And everything's work now. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I thought so too. Great you figured it out. Why don't you provide the solution in the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to delete some lines, here's what i changed from my registration controller :

```
def edit
  @backlink = params[:backlink]
  super
end
```

This way, it appears exactly the way I wanted to. 
Many thanks :)